# jQuery move object to other container and back

Tags: jquery, html, containers, move, back

I am struggling with this problem for a while. Lets say, I have imageA and imageB respectively in containerA and containerB. Additionally, I have containerC.

What I want to do, is:

1. Click on imageA > imageB moves from containerB to containerC. imageA stays in containerA
2. Click again on imageA > imageB moves from containerC back to containerB.
3. Click on imageB > imageA moves from containerA to containerC.
4. etc.

At this moment, I can move imageA and imageB to containerC, but I can't move them back to original places.

HTML code:

```
<div id="containerA">
<img id="imageA" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/tryitimg.gif" alt="imageA">
</div>

<div id="containerB">
<img id="imageB" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png" alt="imageB">
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("#imageA").on('click', function() {
   $("#imageB").appendTo($("#containerC"));
});

$("#imageB").on('click', function() {
   $("#imageA").appendTo($("#containerC"));
});
});
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You're missing the `>` from your `div` elements by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the markup to

```
<div id="containerA">
    <img id="imageA" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/tryitimg.gif" alt="imageA">
</div>

<div id="containerB">
    <img id="imageB" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png" alt="imageB">
</div>

<div id="containerC"></div>
```

and do

```
$(function(){
    $("#imageA").on('click', function() {
        var container = $("#imageB").closest("#containerC").length ? $("#containerA") : $("#containerC");
        $("#imageB").appendTo(container);
    });

    $("#imageB").on('click', function() {
        var container = $("#imageA").closest("#containerC").length ? $("#containerB") : $("#containerC");
        $("#imageA").appendTo(container);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3QY8n/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Note: in JavaScript, you used `$("#containerA") : $("#containerC");` two times. It has to be `$("#containerB") : $("#containerC");` in imageA function.

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom - You're welcome, changed the container ID, small typo there.

Comment: In which place I will have to edit, if I wanted to add more images, moving to containerC and back? imageD from containerD, imageE from containerE, etc.?

Comment: Same procedure I suppose ?

Comment: Hey @adaneo , 
I have another question for you:
I made it on a little other way, see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utCb6/31/) (for some reason it does not work on my browser - the same code works on my computer).
What I want to do, is when I click on one video, other 2 videos goes to other div (each video to seperate div), when I click the same video again, all videos go back to original.
If I click the 2nd video, all videos go to seperate div again, etc.. Any ideas about this?
I have tried your code, tried to implement it in different ways, but I could not manage to make it work. Thanks!